# Twitter Oauth with GUI Java

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am facing problem in get authentication from twitter with java GUI

My program is sample. button to request for authentication code it open browser and give you the code the user have to copy that code and past it in `jtextfield` and write a message and the recipient than click on another button to send the message my problem in send button I am getting (Unable to get the access token.)

I hope some one help me.

button to get authentication code

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer("7VsNoy8OJceAPJ0qbmleWtxRG", "Jh74QXWfuksNwnppeXZLNEq0VqxNCQeeb2m0Q7GrG99NzTtuFV");
RequestToken requestToken = null;
try {
    requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
    //jf.setText(requestToken.getToken());
} catch (TwitterException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(TwitterSK.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL()));
} catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(TwitterSK.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

button to send the message (here's the problem)

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer("7VsNoy8OJceAPJ0qbmleWtxRG", "Jh74QXWfuksNwnppeXZLNEq0VqxNCQeeb2m0Q7GrG99NzTtuFV");
RequestToken requestToken = null;
AccessToken accessToken = null;
try {
    requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
} catch (TwitterException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(TwitterSK.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

String pin = null;
pin = pin_tx.getText();
try {
    if (pin.length() > 0)
    {
        accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, pin);
        storeAccessToken(twitter.verifyCredentials(), accessToken);
        twitter.sendDirectMessage(Tuser.getText(),keyP2.getText());
    }  
} catch (TwitterException te) {
    System.out.println("Unable to get the access token.");
}
```